# how to extract an object from the camera preview android opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to scan a MTG card using OpenCV on android. I have it to where I can detect the edges of the card and even draw an outline around it but am confused on how to extract just the card from the background and then exit from the camera preview. Here is my code so far:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat result = new Mat();
    Mat mask = new Mat();
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Imgproc.Canny(mRgba, result, 40, 120);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(result, result, new Size(9,9), 2, 2);
    Imgproc.findContours(result, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0,0));
    Imgproc.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
    hierarchy.release();

    for ( int contourIdx=0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++ )
    {
        // Minimum size allowed for consideration
        MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f( contours.get(contourIdx).toArray() );
        //Processing on mMOP2f1 which is in type MatOfPoint2f
        double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true)*0.02;
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);

        //Convert back to MatOfPoint
        MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint( approxCurve.toArray() );

        // Get bounding rect of contour
        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);

        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3);
    }
    Bitmap card = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.cols(), result.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(result, card);
    return mRgba;
}
```

}

Here is an example of what it looks like when run the code. As you can see the card is outlined by a red rectangle now but how do I extract just whats in the rectangle, save it to a mat or bitmap and then exit the camera? 
[screenshot of outlined card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKj34.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but can't you just use...

```
return new Mat(mRgba, rect);
```

Comment: it takes a second to line up the card and outline it with the rectangle, so I need a way to tell that the card is outlined correctly before I return that. I hope this makes sense